# Gas estimation failed: execution reverted on goerli with brownie

Tags: gas-limit, brownie, solidity-0.8.x, exceptions

I'm trying to test an onlyOwner function on goerli testnet which's expected to be passed with `pytest.raises(exceptions.VirtualMachineError)` but it keeps getting below error. I added priority_fee and max_fee to the transaction and `set_the_gas_limit_manually: True` and `gas_limit: 300000000` to my brownie-config.yaml file but it keeps throwing the below error and I can't find out where I set sth wrong or what I missed. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

**Terminal: cmd,
python version: 3.10.6,
pytest version: 7.1.3**

**This is the solidity function:**

```
function setTokensData(
        address _token,
        uint8 _rate,
        address _priceFeed
    ) public onlyOwner {
        tokensToRate[_token] = _rate;
        tokensToPriceFeed[_token] = _priceFeed;
        tokenIsApproved[_token] = true;
    }
```

**This is my python test script:**

```
from brownie import network, exceptions, accounts, chain, config, Staking, KoalaToken
from scripts.helpful_scripts import (
    LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS,
    get_contract,
    get_account,
)
from scripts.deploy import (
    deploy_KoalaToken_and_Staking,
)
import pytest
from web3 import Web3


def test_only_owner_can_set_tokens_data():
    # Arrange
    if network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
        pytest.skip()
    account = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key_non_owner"])
    link_token = get_contract("link_token")
    link_usd_price_feed = get_contract("link_usd_price_feed")
    rate = 2
    staking = Staking[-1]
    koala_token = KoalaToken[-1]
    # Act & Assert
    with pytest.raises(exceptions.VirtualMachineError):
        staking.setTokensData(
            link_token,
            rate,
            link_usd_price_feed,
            {
                "from": account,
                "allow_revert": True,
                "priority_fee": 3000000000,
                "max_fee": 15716213,
            },
        )
```

**This is the thrown error:**

```
    ...\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py:1861: in __call__
        return self.transact(*args)
    ...\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py:1734: in transact
        return tx["from"].transfer(
    ...\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py:644: in transfer
        receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
    ...\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py:727: in _make_transaction
        raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
            
self = VirtualMachineError(ValueError("Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted: Ownable: caller is not the owner'. This transaction will likely revert. If 
        you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually."))
        exc = "Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted: Ownable: caller is not the owner'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must 
        set the gas limit manually."
        
            def __init__(self, exc: ValueError) -> None:
                    self.txid: str = ""
                    self.source: str = ""
                    self.revert_type: str = ""
                    self.pc: Optional[int] = None
                    self.revert_msg: Optional[str] = None
                    self.dev_revert_msg: Optional[str] = None
            
                    try:
                        exc = exc.args[0]
                    except Exception:
                        pass
            
                    if not (isinstance(exc, dict) and "message" in exc):
            >           raise ValueError(str(exc)) from None
            E           ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted: Ownable: caller is not the owner'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some of the gas modifying and setting  techniques here:

https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-gas.html